# How to display alert windows or prompt to unregistered users

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, popup

I am setting up a spreadsheet whose users do not necessarily have a Google account nor should be required to log in.

I would like to interact with users in two ways that are possible with the  `Browser` class. One is displaying an alert in a pop-up window, in order to warn users not to edit a field. This is done with `Browser.msgBox` or ̀`ui.alert`. The second thing is requesting an input in a window, which is done nicely with `Browser.inputBox()`.

While my code works fine when I am logged in as owner, it is useless when edited by an unregistered user.

Can I make those function work for unregistered users and if so, how?

Otherwise, are there workarounds to achieve similar functionalities?

Here is a minimal example of what I did:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();   
  var eventRange = event.range;   
  var eventRow = eventRange.getRow();
  var eventCol = eventRange.getColumn();
  if(eventCol == 1){
    protectDateField(ss, eventRow, eventCol)
    }
  }

  function protectDateField(ss, eventRow, eventCol){
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert("Do Not Edit This Field!");
    ss.getRange(eventRow,eventCol).clearContent(); 
    }
```

Comment: It's disabled for security reasons. I don't think there's any workaround.

Comment: Aw, :-s 
That renders the whole concept of shared spreadsheets completely useless IMHO.
Shouldn't it be a way of making a pop-up prompt in javascript without using the functions provided by Google ?

Comment: Can't you just make sheet1 - Whatever greetings you want to inform unregistered users

Comment: Whatever you want to say through Alerts/msgboxes, Say it in first sheet.. Format it with big font size and such.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yet I really want my prompts to work. Especially the input box is important for the design I want.

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

What you want to do it's not possible on Google Sheets.

## Explanation

- To run a script bounded to a spreadsheet the user should be an editor for that spreadsheet.
- Simple triggers can't access services that require authorization to run.
- Some additional restrictions apply when triggers are triggered by anonymous users.

NOTES:

1. The required authorization scopes by each method are included on the documentation section for each method.
2. Anonymous users can't authorize scripts to be ran by installable triggers as the authorization process requires a usar account to log the respective authorization.

For further details see:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers

## Workarounds

There is no way to achieve the desired functionality by solely using Google Sheets, but you could

- create a web app by using Apps Script and embed on it a spreadsheet
- create a web app by using another platform and embed on it spreadsheet

Comment: Last I checked, Anonymous users can run scripts, just not the ones with auth scopes/pop ups(the latter was only recently disabled). Anonymous edits(Public edit access) will trigger ``function onEdit(){console.log(" Somebody edited me.")}``.

Comment: @I'-'I You are right, thank you. I will edit my answer in a moment